# Работа с реализацией Validator

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть такой валидатор:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationValidator implements Validator {

    private final static Pattern PHONE_NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)$");

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> type) {
        return Application.class.equals(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Application application = (Application) target;
        validateMobilePhone(application, errors);
    }

    private void validateMobilePhone(Application application, Errors errors) {
        String mobilePhone = application.getMobilePhone();
        if (!(mobilePhone != null && mobilePhone.length() == 10 && PHONE_NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(mobilePhone).find())) {
            errors.rejectValue("mobile phone", "application.mobilePhone");
        }
    }
}
```

Не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы при создании объекта `Application` или получении по `rest`-запросу вызывался валидатор.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, фразу "при создании объекта `Application`". Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите, чтобы при вызове `new Application(...)` созданный объект передавался в валидатор, и в случае неверных данных что-то происходило (например, падал exception)? Или вы что-то другое имели ввиду?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146298/spring-mvc-how-to-perform-validation
2 способ. Нужно в параметры контроллера добавить валидируемый объект и валидатор. Затем в валидатор кинуть объект и проверить байдинг резалт на ошибки.

Comment: есть два способа валидации в спринге, какой именно вам нужен?